# Trouble getting correct base ouput for ascii image

Tags: java, image, char, int, output

This is just one part of a greater issue I'm having but it's best I ask now before I continue. Essentially I'm trying to write code that uses multiple methods to output a cake image using certain characters. We use the characters "\", "/", and "=" and an int value to get a certain size base that looks something like "\=============/" via user input. The first part I manged to get done since it just asked the user for input that was odd and between 3 and 9 and print an error if it was out of bounds. Afterwards we would use that in the second method that would make a certain sized base. So for instance if the person put a 3 it would print out "\===========================/". The key being that the equal sign is printed 27 times, or 9 more times than what was put in. So if the user put in a 5 it would print 45 equal signs and so forth. The thing is though we have to set the int value in the method to 3 and figure out a formula from there. I'm not sure how to get it to print that many equal signs, or even how to properly call the method in my main since it requires so many parameters. Anybody who can help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
public static void main (String [] args)   {                  

 askForSize();

}

public static int askForSize()    {
    Scanner keybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter an odd integer between 3 and 9: ");
        count = keybd.nextInt();
        if (count > 9 || count < 3) {
            System.out.print("Error: ");
        }
    } while (count < 3 || count > 9);
    return count;
}

public void drawBorder(char backslash,char slash,char equal ,int bricks) {
    char ch1 = '\\';
    char ch2 = '/';
    char ch3 = '=';
    int drawB = 3;
    System.out.print(ch1);
    for (int count = -6; count <= drawB; count++)
        System.out.print(ch3);
    System.out.print(ch2);
}
```

Comment: First, I highly recommend naming your variables something different. `ch1` is a poor name. Instead of `ch3`, I would name it, `equals`, or something along those lines, or simply use the char literal. Second, why start `count` at `-6`? If you are looping until 3 * the user input, start at 0.. and loop until 3 times the user input. Also why are you passing the char parameters to `drawBorder`?

Comment: I took your advice and changed the variables and such alongside making it so count stars at 0 and goes till drawB * 9. I put the char parameters in drawBorder because that was how the assignments listed it but it might be to throw us off or something since If I take them out things become much easier. My only problem now would be seeing how to call it in the main using the user input given in askForSize method. Would I set an int variable = to askForSize and go from there maybe?

Comment: Yes, something like: `int size = askForSize(); drawBorder(size);`

Comment: Also if the parameters are given there in the assignment, it may be in case that your instructor wants you to pass in the characters, in which case you would remove `ch1`, `ch2`, etc and then just use the parameters.

Comment: Thank you two so much, I got this part down now. Now onto the rest.

Comment: No problem. Happy coding